# Responsive design in Android app

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app. This app have to be available on all Android devices. But how can I do responsive design? For example I want to set a background image, but the image will resize to the different resolutions and it's a mess.

Searching on Google I found this solution:

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
if(config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600){
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tablet);
}else{
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

It's this really the only way to develop an Android app for all devices? I have to create an activity and different images for every device? There are more than ten different resolutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to obtain responsive layout result on each device, the good way is to use RelativeLayout and according to child views like button you should use "match_patent" or in older SDK versions "film_patent" attribute.

Link here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

What about images?

Android developer instructions say that there are four drawable resources folders (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi) and there you should put earlier prepared images with suitable size and density.

Link here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I applied one another way. In my app there are relative layouts with match_parent attribute for each child view like button.
Referring to images we prepared images in HD resolutions with 240dpi and app looks nice on each device (Samsung trend lite, Nexus 5).

So to be honest if you're planning to develop your APP for handhelds the best way is to prepare two images (HD and full HD), but that is only my advice;)

Comment: Thanks, I will do what you say, but what about the background images? The background resizes automatically, so depends on the device resolution the background image will deform. How can I solve this?

Comment: Thats true, background images resize on different devices too. I did the same with background images. On small resolution devices and HD i prepared one HD image and for full HD another one. But I also tested one HD image (240dpi) on each device and result was very good. It depends on how much you pay attention to app design (for games its good to prepare few images but for ordinary app you can try my solution, it works me.)